# Forward all ports incoming to a specific IP to internal IP address

Tags: port-forwarding

centos 5.x

I'm wondering how I can forward "all" ports incoming to a eth0:alias IP to a specific internal IP address.

I have found ways to-do this for particular ports, but I wish to forward every port.

Can someone point me in the right direction please!

:-)

Answer (score 6):

Pablo is absolutely right, but I might as well provide a sample line here, which assumes your eth0:alias address is 1.2.3.5 and your internal IP of choice is 10.1.1.2:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -i eth0 -d 1.2.3.5 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.11.1.2
```

If you want UDP as well, either have a second line for udp or just remove `-p tcp`.

This answer is no substitute for reading and understanding a good HOWTO, but it gives you some idea of where to start looking.

Comment: It didn't work like this, but without the `-p tcp` it worked. Not sure if this is important, but I also added `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
` ( I am on Debian stretch)

Answer (score 2):

Hi I believe this step by step how to should be what you need.

http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables

You want to go with NAT instead of PAT.