# Port Forwarding all ports in UFW to a VPN Client on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, port-forwarding, ufw, wireguard

I am running a VPN Wireguard server on Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to forward all ports from the server to a vpn client on 10.10.10.2. As of now, I have perfected port forwarding for single ports. In `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, the line that does this looks like the following:

```
# Port forward port 80 to VPN Client at 10.10.10.2
-A PREROUTING -i enp1s0 -d my.public.server.ip  -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:80
```

This successfully forwards port 80 from the vpn server's public IP to the VPN Client on 10.10.10.2. NOW, I would like to convert this rule to forward all traffic from my.public.server.ip to all ports on my VPN Client 10.10.10.2, instead of having to forward individual ports.

How can I go about port forwarding all traffic from the VPN server to the VPN client in one line in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/234370/forward-all-ports-incoming-to-a-specific-ip-to-internal-ip-address ?